Powermail multiple predefined receivers possible?
I was asking the same question on TYPO3Slack and the Powermail Git, but no answers so far.
TYPO3 v10, Powermail V8.5.1 (will be upgraded soon, I promise ;))
Is it possible to use a field multiple times to get more than one receiver? The Predefined receivers example works so far, but I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this:
emailA = CASE
emailA {
    key.data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|fieldA
    12345678=TEXT
    12345678.value=mail@test.de
    default = TEXT
    default.value = defaultmail@test.de
}

#now checking the same field again:
emailB = CASE                            
emailB {
    key.data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|fieldA
    key.stdWrap.crop = 3 | | 0
    123 = TEXT
    123.value = anothermail@test.de
    default = TEXT
    default.value = defaultmail@test.de
}

# now make a list of mails to be sent
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.predefinedReceiver.receivers1.email = {emailA.value},{emailB.value}

The code is just a mockup and does not work. But would it be possible?

predefinedReceiver.receivers1.email can be a comma-separated list of several e-mail addresses. And it can be any cObject. I.e. you only have to assemble the list correctly (i.e. with commas)
https://github.com/in2code-de/powermail/blob/3841cb350306896812bd1ba228795948f85ef438/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/setup.typoscript#L115
